# SuperCollider doesn't start DotFox

Tags: python, supercollider

I'm just following the tutorial below.
https://foxdot.org/installation/

My environment is macOS 10.14.6, python3.6

I did

1, brew install SuperCollider 3.11.1.

2, pip install FoxDot 0.8.11

3, installed sc3-plugins-3.11.0-macOS.zip from its official page

And I activate SuperCollider and enter `Quarks.install("FoxDot")` then it's installed successfully.
But when I do `FoxDot.start`, it says there is no class defined.

```
ERROR: Class not defined.
  in interpreted text
  line 1 char 6:

  DotFox.start
```

I don't know why this happens and it takes me hours to know what's really happening.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I got this solved by myself. You actually needed to run foxdot.scd file you can download here https://foxdot.org/installation/. I don't know why SuperCollider Quarks doesn't work though...any headsup?

Comment: I got this solved by myself. You actually needed to run foxdot.scd file you can download here https://foxdot.org/installation/. I don't know why SuperCollider Quarks doesn't work though...any headsup?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try executing `s.boot;`
in SuperCollider before running `FoxDot.start;` ?

Also, just checking, you have recompiled the class library after the Quarks install? To do this, type cmd+shift+L (on mac; on windows it is ctrl+shift+L)

Really strange to get DotFox!!